# Yosemite cannot detect SD card

Tags: macos, disk-utility, external-disk, sd-card

I know their is a flood of these questions but I have a late 2013 macbook pro with yosemite 10.10.5 installed on it.

My problem is it won't read some of my SD cards, i've run disk util with the pny sd card inserted and I get this

```
bash-3.2$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         120.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           *120.1 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 F57E540D-B47C-40C6-BDE1-F9EEB04734AB
                                 Unencrypted
bash-3.2$
```

Whats strange is when I insert another sd card (a samsung card) It comes up OK

```
bash-3.2$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         120.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           *120.1 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 F57E540D-B47C-40C6-BDE1-F9EEB04734AB
                                 Unencrypted
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *8.0 GB     disk2
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 NO NAME                 8.0 GB     disk2s1
bash-3.2$
```

I've tested the PNY cards in my iPad with an sd card reader and the photos come up OK, and all the photos appear on my camera as well so the SD card themselves seem to be OK

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The only difference is the software update. I'm using the same SD card in my camera that I have used for the last year without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly common for recent MBPs to have somewhat glitchy SD card readers. With certain cards, and especially with cheaper microSD adapters, I have to make sure I don't push the card all the way in or it might either not show up at all, or show up but keep getting ejected mid-write.

Comment: What I don't understand is it's been absolutely fine until the recent update to OS X

Comment: Since it's not just failing to mount but actually not showing up at all I have a hard time seeing how a software update could be the culprit. Have you tried both firmly pushing it further in and keeping it out a bit?
And have you checked if there might be any lint or similar in the reader?

Answer (score 1):

If you're convinced it's software (or want to rule that out), you can download the 10.9 installer (or other) and run it to install the OS onto an external drive. It's probably not that, but you can rule that in or out.

Before going to that length, open terminal and look at the following command - before you insert the card and then compare after inserting and waiting 15 seconds.

```
system_profiler SPCardReaderDataType
```

You can also get this information in the System Information app. Open the Hardware triangle if needed and then select **Card Reader**

You can press Command R to refresh the window - so wait the 15 seconds after inserting to be sure the system has polled. You should see that the card itself reads quite rapidly, and depending on the filesystem - it might be running through a slow `fsck` check before showing it in Finder.

Basically, you can tell if the hardware negotiates at a low level pretty reliably and the software delay is in how thorough a check is running or if you need to use Disk Utility to erase and repartition/reformat the storage card.

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar problem. I put the (FAT formatted) card in the slot of my iMac and I can see the muted volume on Disc Utility and also on the system report. However, it will not show on the desktop and, intermittently, I can use Go To Folder and sometimes it will show in the list of volumes but will not allow opening (Road Closed sign). Other times it will allow full path and shows all the files. This has happened on two cards from two different devices, If I format the SD card on the iMac it will function properly.
All this is a new phenomenon and has worked with both cameras and both SD cards. Command line in terminal works OK and shows everything.
It makes me think I should Zap the Pram ? People say that cures a host of problems